# Postgres: insert new row in table if the table does not have records where column_name = 'abc' occurs N times?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I would like to do this in one transaction

So let's take table with columns:

```
user -> [first_name, last_name]
```

The use case is that we don't want to insert a new record into a table, if the table already has records where `user.first_name = 'ABC'` occurs 5 times;

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES 
('john', 'doe') ...
```

Apologies if this is simple, am a developer and SQL is not my strong point.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something with triggers

Or you do somewhat complexer `INSERT`

Which allows only 5 *John* in your table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "user" ("first_name" varchar(16),"last_name" varchar(50) )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into "user" 
> select 'john', 'doe' 
> where (select count(*) from "user" where "first_name" = 'john') < 5
> ```

> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into "user" 
> select 'john', 'doe2' 
> where (select count(*) from "user" where "first_name" = 'john') < 5
> ```

> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into "user" 
> select 'john', 'doe3' 
> where (select count(*) from "user" where "first_name" = 'john') < 5
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into "user" 
> select 'john', 'doe4' 
> where (select count(*) from "user" where "first_name" = 'john') < 5
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into "user" 
> select 'john', 'doe5' 
> where (select count(*) from "user" where "first_name" = 'john') < 5
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into "user" 
> select 'john', 'doe6' 
> where (select count(*) from "user" where "first_name" = 'john') < 5
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM "user"
> ```
>
> ```
> first_name | last_name
> :--------- | :--------
> john       | doe      
> john       | doe2     
> john       | doe3     
> john       | doe4     
> john       | doe5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fbaca58ea93659fc34c9dd57978941a6)*

Answer (score 0):

I believe a query like this is what you're looking for, in one transaction / one query batch:

```
WITH CTE_Users_GroupByFirstName AS
(
    SELECT first_name, COUNT(1) AS first_name_count
    FROM users2
    GROUP BY first_name 
)
    
INSERT INTO users
SELECT 'john', 'doe'
FROM users AS U
LEFT JOIN CTE_Users_GroupByFirstName AS C
    ON U.first_name = C.first_name
WHERE U.first_name = 'john'
    AND
    (
        C.first_name_count IS NULL
        OR C.first_name_count < 5
    )
Limit 1;
```